# How to return class type for Scrapy Crawler?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this method in my starter.py

```
def startSpider(spider_name,spider_class):
    configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    runner.crawl(spider_name+"."+spider_class)
```

Because crawler sends class type it is not executing the code.

And I get this error.

```
'Spider not found: migros.migrosSpider'
```

It probably seems like just a spider name so how can I return my spider name and spider class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it works well.

```
    name = 'spiders.'+spider_name

    i = importlib.import_module(name)
    class_ = getattr(i, spider_class)

    configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    runner.crawl(class_)
```